# Uniformizer of a smooth point in $X=Z(f)$ with $f$ in $k[x,y]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f$ be a polynomial in $k[x,y]$, $X=Z(f)\subset \mathbb{A}^2$ and $P\in X$ smooth, such that $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})(P)\ne 0$. How can we prove that $y-y(P)$ is a uniformizer of $X$ at $P$?

Comment: What is your definition of uniformizer?

Comment: @TabesBridges a generator of m_p/(m_p)^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set things up, we may take $P=(0,0)$ after a translation to make our lives easier (we'll assume $k$ is algebraically closed in order to do this). We'll also write $\mathcal{O}_P=(k[x,y]/(f))_{(x,y)}$ for the local ring.

Now write $f=p(x,y)x-q(y)$ where $p,q\in k[x,y]$ are polynomials and $q$ has no constant term. Taking the partial derivative with respect to $x$, we get that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=x\cdot\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + p$, so after evaluating at $P=(0,0)$ we get that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(P)=p(P)$, so $p(0,0)\neq 0$ and $p$ has nonzero constant term.

Now we examine $f$ in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_P$: $f=0$, so $q(y)=p(x,y)x$. But since $p$ has nonzero constant term, it's a unit in $\mathcal{O}_P$. So $x$ is in the ideal generated by $y$, and therefore $y$ must generate the entire maximal ideal.

Comment: @PouyaLayeghi please consider leaving a comment before suggesting an edit, especially for such a recent post as this.

Comment: I am sorry. Thanks for mentioning this and also for your answer. I should mention that for using the translation, it is not so clear for me that we can do that and where we are using k is algebraically closed. It will be great if you write more about this.

Comment: Translating a $k$-rational point $(a,b)$ to the origin corresponds to the automorphism of $k[x,y]$ given by $x\mapsto x-a,y\mapsto y-b$. Since all closed points are $k$-rational when $k$ is algebraically closed, we can translate any closed point of $\Bbb A^2_k$ to the origin when $k$ is algebraically closed. If $k$ isn't algebraically closed, there are closed points we can't translate to the origin and one has to take a little more care with how to write up this whole setup (though the idea is the same).